# Log4j SMTPappender with HTML mail

Tags: log4j, appender

I would like to use log4j and send email in HTML format (Using SMTP Appender). Is it possible in log4j out of the box.

If so please point me to right examples

Comment: I have only used log4net since I'm in the .NET camp, but since it's a port of log4j, perhaps the log4net docs will help.  I used this page to help me get all of my appenders configured.  http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Logback provides a Layout that formats the logs as HTML.  Combining that with an SMTPAppender would send email in HTML format.

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicHTMLLayout

Direct quote from the page:

> The HTMLLayout is often used in
>   conjunction with SMTPAppender so that
>   outgoing email is pleasantly formatted
>   in HTML.

You could even take the source code and modify it, pretty easily, to suit your needs.

http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/html/HTMLLayout.html

---

They provide the following code to initilaize the appender:

```
 <appender name="SMTP" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
      <pattern>%relative%thread%mdc%level%class%msg</pattern>
    </layout>
    <From>sender.email@domain.net</From>
    <SMTPHost>mail.domain.net</SMTPHost>
    <Subject>LastEvent: %class - %msg </Subject>
    <To>destination.email@domain.net</To> 
  </appender>
```

---

I hope that helps in some way,

-gMale